# Get Emulator list from Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

As per [ChromeDriver site](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation), the user can use the emulators created/present in the chrome for Selenium execution.

[Detailed View Here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports).

[image]

I wanted to display all the created/available emulators from `Chrome`. `Chrome` could be storing that details in some json file or something.If so how to access it and print it in `Java`

Comment: @yeppe not from api. From local machine where chrome is installed

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent... check this..A browser’s user agent string (UA) helps identify which browser is being used, what version, and on which operating system. When feature detection APIs are not available, use the UA to customize behavior or content to specific browser versions.

Comment: Yes I got it,I'm using that as of now . But I dont want that,I want to get the emulators list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did a **Notepad++** `Find in Files` and found it.

The data is stored in JSON format in file

> C:\Users\Your UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences

Under Key

> devtools>preferences>standardEmulatedDeviceList

I have used Jackson to parse the JSON

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Map map = mapper.readValue(
                    new File("C:\\Users\\<UserName>\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Preferences"),
                    Map.class);
            Map devTools = (Map) map.get("devtools");
            Map preferences = (Map) devTools.get("preferences");
            String standardEmulatedDeviceList = (String) preferences.get("standardEmulatedDeviceList");
            List emulatorMap = mapper.readValue(standardEmulatedDeviceList, List.class);
            System.out.println(emulatorMap.size());
            for (Object object : emulatorMap) {
                Map device = (Map) object;
                System.out.println(device.get("title"));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```