# How to get all available devices listed in Chrome Developer tool -> Emulated Device programmatically?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I want to get the list of emulated devices available in Chrome. Is there any way to get the whole list programmatically?

Basically, I would like to run my test on several emulated mobile device and mobile device name will be passed via a config file. I would like to check whether that device is available in list of chrome emulated device.

Worst case, I can use directly the passed device name and handle the exception thrown But I would like to do a check before only.

Comment: You can get them on https://github.com/AndreyBelym/chrome-emulated-devices-list/blob/master/devices.md

Comment: Thanks, But won't it be outdated after sometime? I don't want to keep updating this list. So, I was looking to get it through CDT somehow, if possible.

Comment: You may take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587659/get-emulator-list-from-chrome

Comment: Thanks! it solved my problem @KnightKing